# Error undetected chrome driver and random user agents

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, user-agent, undetected-chromedriver

when I use the undetected chrome driver module and at the same time I use different user agents when the browser is opened, no user agent is applied. However if I remove the undetected chrome driver and use webdriver instead it does apply a random user agent. Below I put the code without the undetected chrome driver module. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import os
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
import asyncio
import random
import json

token = ''
chat_id = ''


def get_random_user_agent():
    user_agents = [
        # User-Agents Ordenador
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.5738.222 Safari/537.36',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.5766.208 Safari/537.36',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; rv:113.0esr) Gecko/20010101 Firefox/113.0esr/V8407U7XqmBO',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.5791.223 Safari/537.36 Edg/113.0.1521.39',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_15_1; rv:115.0) Gecko/20110101 Firefox/115.0',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.5745.219 Safari/537.36',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_16_3) AppleWebKit/616.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.2.84 Safari/616.13',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.5757.216 Safari/537.36',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/116.0.5821.216 Chrome/116.0.5821.216 Safari/537.36',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.5758.223 Safari/537.36',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.5842.209 Safari/537.36',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_10) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.5768.195 Safari/537.36',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.5800.222 Safari/537.36',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/116.0.5791.199 Chrome/116.0.5791.199 Safari/537.36',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.5798.218 Safari/537.36',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.5752.204 Safari/537.36',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_0_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1.67 Safari/631.15',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) Gecko/20102614 Firefox/114.0',

        
        # User-Agents de móvil
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 11; TVBOX) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.5748.222 Mobile Safari/537.36',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Android; Mobile; rv:115.0) Gecko/115.0 Firefox/115.0',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; BAH3-L09) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.5821.213 Mobile Safari/537.36',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Android; Mobile; rv:114.0esr) Gecko/114.0esr Firefox/114.0esr',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 11; X88pro10.q2.0.6330.d4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.5760.215 Mobile Safari/537.36',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Android; Mobile; rv:114.0) Gecko/114.0 Firefox/114.0',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.2.23 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.2.84 Mobile/N4D0SY Safari/632.24',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Android 10; Tablet; rv:113.0) Gecko/113.0 Firefox/113.0',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Android; Tablet; rv:115.0) Gecko/115.0 Firefox/115.0',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/618.31.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1 Mobile/IFS1K6 Safari/618.31.8',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.4.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.5.72 Mobile/678BM5 Safari/624.6',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/625.19.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.6 Mobile/TQQFTT Safari/625.19.3',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Android 11; Mobile; rv:114.0) Gecko/114.0 Firefox/114.0',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/622.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.3 Mobile/TIOIVQ Safari/622.24',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.5 Mobile/HMV5LW Safari/630.21',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1 Mobile/1X132W Safari/614.33',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.4 Mobile/6J87JZ Safari/616.26',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.4.14 Mobile/AF61R3 Safari/626.14',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Android; Tablet; rv:113.0) Gecko/113.0 Firefox/113.0',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/621.30.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0.53 Mobile/79EXL0 Safari/621.30.2',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; M40_EEA) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.5762.219 Mobile Safari/537.36',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0 Mobile/NSBJYM Safari/620.6.13',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 11; M40_EEA) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.5765.212 Mobile Safari/537.36',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.6.95 Mobile/JDJJVY Safari/624.28',
    ]
    random_user_agent = random.choice(user_agents)
    return random.choice(user_agents)
    

def enviar_notificacion_telegram(mensaje):
    url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendMessage'
    data = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'text': mensaje}
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
    response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
    return response.json()

def main():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--enable-logging")
    options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False) 
    
    
    
    
    
    
    file = open('link.txt', 'r')
    link = file.readlines()[0].strip()

    with open('details.txt', 'r') as details_file:
        data = details_file.readlines()[0].strip()
        _, refresh_times = data.split('>')
        refresh_times = [float(time.strip()) for time in refresh_times.split(',')]

    while True:
        try:
            user_agent = get_random_user_agent()
            options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
            refresh_time = random.choice(refresh_times)
            
            

            driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
            driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})") 
            
            
        
            driver.get(link)
            print("User-Agent:", user_agent)
            
            
    
            condition = EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#\\#tickets-iframe-m'))
            iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(condition)
            driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

            condition = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#buynow'))
            first_option = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(condition)
            os.system('sound.mp3')
            mensaje = 'A comprar mi loko'
            enviar_notificacion_telegram(mensaje)
            time.sleep(360)  # Esperar 5 minutos
            driver.close()
            driver.quit()

        except Exception as e:
            print('>>> Product not available, rechecking')
            try:
                print('Waiting for', refresh_time, 'seconds before rechecking...')
                time.sleep(refresh_time)  # Esperar el tiempo aleatorio
                driver.close()
                driver.quit()
            except:
                pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I want to be able to use the undetected chrome driver module and spawn distinct user agents from my list every time the browser is opened.